# Access denied and getting Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page, after upgrading plugins Spring Security core to 2.0 version in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using grails 2.3.3 and groovy 2.2.0 version for my project. I was working fine until I decided to upgrade spring security core 1.2.7.3, ui 0.2 and acl 1.1.1 to spring security core 2.0, ui 1.0 and acl 2.0. I upgraded successfully. But When I try to login, I get "Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page." denied access message.

I have created users in bootstrap.groovy file which is below.

**Bootstrap.groovy**

```
import com.vproc.member.Address;
import com.vproc.member.Profile;
import com.vproc.member.Role ;

class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->


                def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
                def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
                def guestRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_GUEST') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_GUEST').save(failOnError: true)
                def csrRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_CSR') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_CSR').save(failOnError: true)

                //PersonRole.create adminUser, adminRole
                def address = new Address( city : 'Pune' , stateCode : 'MH' , countryCode : 'IN'   )

                def adminProfile = Profile.findByEmailAddress('sachin.jha@gmail.com' )?: new Profile(
                        //privacyLevel: ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private,
                        emailAddress:  "sachin.jha@gmail.com" ,
                        phoneNumber: "9325507992",
                        //status : 'Active'
                        )  //.save( failOnError: true)

                def adminPerson = Person.findByUsername( 'admin') ?: new Person( username : 'admin' ,  password : 'passw0rd' , enabled: true , firstName: 'admin' , lastName : 'user' , profile: adminProfile , status: StatusEnum.Active ).save( failOnError: true) ;

                def vprocOrganization = Organization.findByOrgName('VPROCURE') ?: new Organization ( orgName: 'VPROCURE' , orgSize : 100 , mailingAddress: address, contact: adminPerson ).save( failOnError: true)

                def vprocCustomer = Customer.findByParty( vprocOrganization) ?: new Customer ( party: vprocOrganization, status: StatusEnum.Active  ).save(failOnError: true) ;


                def adminUser = Subscriber.findByParty(adminPerson) ?: new Subscriber(  party: adminPerson, customer: vprocCustomer , status: StatusEnum.Active ).save( failOnError: true)

                if ( !adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
                        SubscriberRole.create adminUser, adminRole
                }

    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
       return it?.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
    }


                def userProfile = Profile.findByEmailAddress( 'sachin.jha.user@gmail.com') ?: new Profile(
                                //privacyLevel: ProfilePrivacyLevelEnum.Private,
                                emailAddress: "sachin.jha.user@gmail.com",
                                phoneNumber : "9325507992",
                                //status : 'Active'
                                ) //.save( failOnError: true)

                def userPerson = Person.findByUsername( 'plainuser') ?: new Person(username: 'plainuser', password : 'passw0rd' , enabled: true , firstName: 'plain' , lastName : 'user' , profile: userProfile , status: StatusEnum.Active).save( failOnError: true) ;

                def plainUser = Subscriber.findByParty(userPerson) ?: new Subscriber(  party: userPerson, customer: vprocCustomer , status: StatusEnum.Active ).save( failOnError : true )

                if ( !plainUser.authorities.contains(userRole)){
                        SubscriberRole.create  plainUser, userRole
                }

                Category electornicsCat = Category.findByName('Electronics') ?: new Category( name:"Electronics" , description: "Electronics market").save(failOnError: true);
                Category realEstateCat = Category.findByName('Real Estate') ?: new Category( name:"Real Estate" , description: "Real Estate market").save(failOnError: true);

                SubCategory subcatServices = SubCategory.findByNameAndCategory( 'Services' , electornicsCat ) ?: new SubCategory( name: 'Services', category: electornicsCat).save(failOnError: true);
                SubCategory subcatConsumerGoods = SubCategory.findByNameAndCategory( 'Consumer Goods' , electornicsCat ) ?: new SubCategory( name: 'Consumer Goods', category: electornicsCat).save(failOnError: true);
                SubCategory subcatFlate= SubCategory.findByNameAndCategory('Flate',realEstateCat) ?: new SubCategory(name: 'Flate', category: realEstateCat).save(failOnError: true)
                SubCategory subcatHousing = SubCategory.findByNameAndCategory('House',realEstateCat) ?: new SubCategory(name: 'House', category: realEstateCat).save(failOnError: true)

                /*vprocCustomer.addToSubscribers(amdinUser)
                vprocCustomer.addToSubscribers(plainUser)
                vprocCustomer.save( failOnError : true);*/

    }

    def destroy = {
    }

}
```

**Config.groovy**

```
grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format  
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.resources.modules = {


    'custom-bootstrap' {

        dependsOn 'bootstrap'

        resource url:[dir: 'less', file: 'custom-bootstrap.less'], attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css']

    }


}


// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

   error  'grails.app'

 /*  root {
      error 'stdout'
      info 'stdout'
      warn 'stdout'
      debug 'stdout'
      additivity = true
   }*/
}

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
/*grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.vproc.member.Person'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.vproc.member.PersonRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.vproc.member.Role'*/


grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/login/selectOrg' :     [],
    '/enquiry2/**':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/subscriber/**':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/contact/*':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/**':               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:

grails.attachmentable.poster.evaluator = { getPrincipal() }

// twitter boot strap

grails.plugins.twitterbootstrap.fixtaglib = true
grails.plugins.twitterbootstrap.defaultBundle = 'bundle_bootstrap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm='bcrypt'

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
    plugins {
        build ':tomcat:7.0.47'
        runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.4'
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        compile ":class-diagram:0.5.2"
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
        runtime ':resources:1.2'
        runtime ":prototype:1.0"
        compile ":webxml:1.4.1"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
        compile ":attachmentable:0.3.0"
        compile ":avatar:0.6.3"
        runtime ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1'
        compile ":cloud-bees:0.6.2"
        compile ":jquery-datatables:1.7.5"
        compile ":jquery-validation:1.9"
        compile ":jquery-validation-ui:1.4.7"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
        compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"
        compile ":fields:1.3"
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"
        compile ":mail:1.0.1"
        compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
        compile ":burning-image:0.5.1"
    }
}
```

**Note: With previous versions of spring security core, I was able to login with users created from bootstrap. But now I facing access denied issue. Any take on this !**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried with following solution suggested by @burt-beckwith from [grails mailing thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/spring-security-2-0-RC2-annotations-td4652662.html)  and worked for me like charm and which is following.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/logout/**':                     ['permitAll']
]
```

I made only one change that differs from thread because what thread says, did not work for me. SO I made some changes, which is following:

**grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false**

A big thanks to @burt-beckwith.

Comment: Excellent solution..!

Answer (score 2):

You need add **login and logout** rules:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    // === THIS TWO LINES, for logout and login
    '/logout/**' :     ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
    '/login/**' :     ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],

    '/login/selectOrg' :     [],
    '/login/selectOrg' :     [],
    '/enquiry2/**':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/subscriber/**':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/contact/*':         ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN'],
    '/**':               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Comment: hi @ignacio-ocampom, I tried with  your suggestion but getting same error. Anything else I can try here ?

Comment: Have your restarted your app?

Comment: hi @@ignacio-ocampom, yes I cleaned and restarted it many a times :(

Comment: I found your error! you have **grails.plugin.spr...** and you must have **grails.plugins.spr...**, **plugins** in plural, updated my answer

Comment: hi @@ignacio-ocampom , that is right i.e. it would be grails.plugins.spr. according to updated version of spring security core.

Comment: Can you update your code? I see the same error because you are using **plugin** instead of **plugins**

Comment: Yes I am using plugin instead of plugins and it is according latest version of spring security core 2.0

Answer (score 2):

the new update of the security plugin uses a pessimistic  approach for url locking, meaning that it locks the access to all the urls by default unless explicitly specified. So what might be happening in your case that after successful authentication, your default success url might be locked by the new version of the plugin. There are three solutions to this :

1) Use @burt-beckwith solution and change the rejectPublicInvocations parameter under *config.groovy*

**grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false**

2) Unblock your default success url eg:

**'/user/**' :     ['ROLE_ADMIN']**

or

**'/homepage/**' :     ['permitAll']**

3) Explicitly define permission in your success controller or action eg:

Controller:
**@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'])**

### class user{

### --

}

Action:

**@Secured(['permitAll'])**

### def homepage(){

### --

}

Hope this helps.